# How to make onSuccess to intent email

Tags: java, android, kotlin, email

i'm using this code

```
try {
            val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            emailIntent.type = "plain/text"
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("mail2012@gmail.com"))
            emailIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "ID: " + idn.text.toString()
            )
            emailIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Full Name" + name.text.toString())

            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail By Gmail..."))
            } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@CreateapplicationActivity,
                    "There are no email clients installed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_error_sending_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

how to call onsuccess to open another activity ofter sending email successfully

if i use

```
.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail")
```

to open gmail

Comment: The user can always choose from a lot of apps. They behave different. Try to use startActivityForResult and implement onActivityResult to begin with. There is no onSucces.

Comment: if i make 
    .setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail")
to open gmail 
how can i do onsuccess to it ?

Comment: @blackapps: "Try to use startActivityForResult and implement onActivityResult to begin with" -- `ACTION_SEND` is not documented to work with `startActivityForResult()`. Few if any apps will return a result, including `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: "if i make .setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail") to open gmail" -- please do not do that. First, not everybody has access to Gmail. Second, not everybody wants to use Gmail. Third, that activity name is an implementation detail and could change at any time. "how to call onsuccess to open another activity ofter sending email successfully" -- you cannot find out about "sending email successfully". That would be a privacy violation. Whether the user chooses to send an email is up to the user and their email app, not you.